# Failed to load module script - importing classes in index.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

I am trying to load these two classes and I get the below error:

> "Failed to load module script: The server responded with a
>   non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is
>   enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."

```
<script type="module">
    import { A, B } from './js/dist/loader';
</script>

<body>
   <div ng-view></div>

   <script src="js/lib.js"></script>
   <script src="js/main.js"></script>
   <script src="js/build/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

From MDN:
"To get modules to work correctly in a browser, you need to make sure that your server is serving them with a Content-Type header that contains a JavaScript MIME type such as `text/javascript`. If you don't, you'll get a strict MIME type checking error along the lines of "The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type" and the browser won't run your JavaScript."

I would probably start by taking a look at the header your server is sending over when delivering the pages.